# 'python' is not recognized anaconda path

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd, anaconda

I have installed python 2.7 with anaconda. When I type "python" in my anaconda terminal. Everything works perfect!

When I type "python" in my windows cmd I got this error message :

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.enter code here
```

But when I write the path

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python.exe
```

python works.

I have followed [those steps](https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/) to set my environnemental varibale path. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\
```

To your path variable in environment variables setting on windows and then restart the terminal and it should work. Changes won't be reflected in already running terminal.

Comment: Add `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2` to `PATH`, not the full path of the executable.